# Generate Regular Expression for First Name Last Name

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a Regular Expression for First Name and Last Name Only with only 2 words with only 1 Space.

Currently my regular expression is here : https://regex101.com/r/WigXOo/1

I have tried the below regular expression:

`[A-Z][a-z]+(\s|,)[A-Z][a-z]{1,19}`

it is validating correctly :

**Sunil Kumar (Correct)**

But it is allowing third Name like: Sunil Kumar 123 (Correct)

I want my results like below :

Correct Output:

**Sunil Kumar** (correct)

InCorrect Output:

- **Sunil Kumar 123** (incorrect) (I want only first and second name)
- **SUnil Kumar** (incorrect) (needed only 1 letter from 1st name and 2nd letter from second name would be capital)
- **Sunil   Kumar** (incorrect) (needed only single space between 1st and 2nd name) (there are 2 spaces between first name and second name)

Please help.

Comment: What is your problem you said Sunil Kumar (correct) and Sunil Kumar (incorrect) but there is no difference between them.

Comment: Obligatory [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Also, go read a regex tutorial. You need start and end anchors. Please read [ask] and share your research. "What have you tried" does not mean "Show the code that does not work", it means "Show what you tried getting that code to work".

Comment: there are 2 spaces between first name and last name I have mentioned that.

Comment: It doesn't match the 2 spaces version anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can add anchors to your expression to match the whole input i.e. `^` and `$` so your expression would become:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(\s|,)[A-Z][a-z]{1,19}$
```

Comment: If this is the answer, the question is a dupe of [How do I match an entire string with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123455/how-do-i-match-an-entire-string-with-a-regex).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thought there would be one, flagged now

Comment: Thanks @TheLethalCoder it is the same that I want, Thanks once again