# Why do I get an unexpected result from my regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I am currently testing input validation for a project, and i am using regex.

I am trying to see if the content of a TextBox is a decimal number before i am trying to parse it.

For this I am using the expression `\d+([\.\,]{1}\d+)?`

I expect it to check if there are one or more digits, then zero or one of the combination of either a point or a comma and one or more digits.

Valid inputs would be:

123

12.3

1,23

Invalid inputs would be:

12.

.123

1...2

1.2.3.3

After testing it with different, known wrong inputs, it seems like the expression does not work as i would expect it to. Am I missing something?

The code i am using is:

```
private bool validateFloatNumber(string Text, TextBox Box)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("\\d+([\\.\\,]{1}\\d+)?");
            bool result = regex.IsMatch(Text);
            if (!result)
            {
                if (Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    Box.Background = Brushes.Gray;
                }
                else
                {
                    Box.Background = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Box.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I tested it with the input `1...1` and the value written in `results` were `true`

[Here is an image of the debug and the wrong value given in result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUJP2.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What event is called for TextBox validation?

Comment: Try a regex tester for your samples, like this one http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Would a single digit be valid?

Comment: @Rob I call it when i push a button, this is not an event handler

Comment: @Yaman I have tried it at regex101 and it yielded the correct results

Comment: @JvdV a single digit should be valid

Comment: @Stephan, was it also a .NET engine, some engines behave different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be that `regex.IsMatch(Text)` returns true if there is a match *anywhere* in the string. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123455/how-do-i-match-an-entire-string-with-a-regex) for an explanation how to match the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

By no means a `RegEx` expert, but maybe:

```
^(\d|\d+[.,]?\d+)$
```

This would test for either:

- `\d` - A single digit
- `\d+` - One or more digits with `[.,]?` zero or one dot or comma followed by `\d+` at least one more digit.

[Online Test](https://regex101.com/r/R5wiOh/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static bool validateFloatNumber(string Text, TextBox Box)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]{1,9}([,.][0-9]{1,4})?$");
        bool result = regex.IsMatch(Text);
        if (!result)
        {
            if (Text.Length == 0)
            {
                Box.Background = Brushes.Gray;
            }
            else
            {
                Box.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Box.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

^ **Beginning** Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (**m**) is enabled

**[**  **Character set.** Match any character in the set.

**0-9** **Range**. Matches a character in the range "0" to "9" (char code 48 to 57). Case sensitive.

**]**

**{1,9}** **Quantifier**.  Match between 1 and 9 of the preceding token.

**(**

**Capturing group #1**. Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.

**[** **Character set.** Match any character in the set.

**,** Character. Matches a "," character (char code 44).

**.** Character. Matches a "." character (char code 46).

**]**

**[** **Character set.**  Match any character in the set.

**0-9 Range**.  Matches a character in the range. "0" to "9" (char code 48 to 57). Case sensitive.

**]**

**{1-4} Quantifier**.  Match between 1 and 4 of the preceding token.

**)**

**? Quantifier.**  Match between 0 and 1 of the preceding token.

**$ End.**  Matches the end of the string, or the end of a line if the multiline flag (**m**) is enabled.