# Powershell regex how to prevent match when additional characters are present in the string being tested

Tags: regex, powershell

I am validating input strings using regex.

The input string must be 8 characters long, it must begin with an 'E', followed by six digits then either another digit or 'X'.

My Powershell comparison is as follows:

`$Input -match "E\d{6}[\dX]"`

This returns true for valid values and false for invalid values, as long as they are 8 characters or less.  Unfortunately it also returns true for values where the first 8 characters match the expression but additional unwanted characters are also present, e.g:

| input | desired return | actual return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Invalid1 | False | False |
| E012345X | True | True |
| E012345Xblahblahblah | False | True |

No doubt this is by design, however I would like it to return false for the last example.  I cannot simply truncate the input as the script is validating existing data and needs to highlight the error.

Is there a way to do what I want in regex, or do I just have to use a combination of regex then test the string length separately?

Comment: You should include the beginn (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string to your pattern. So it should be `$Input -match '^E\d{6}[\dX]$'`

Comment: Also, if you need the leading `E` and the trailing `X` to be all caps, (don't know if that's the case though), use the `-cmatch` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your question

```
$Input -match "^E\d{6}[\dX]$"
```

Answer (score 3):

All the relevant information is in the existing answers, but let me try to present a systematic overview:

- **PowerShell's [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operator by default matches *any substring*** of its input string(s)<sup>[1]</sup> (albeit only ever the *first* occurrence), so **in order to match the input *in full*, enclosing a regex pattern in `^...$`  is required**, where anchor `^` represents the start, and `$` the end of the input.

  - With *single-line* input, `^` and `$` work as described, ditto with *multiline* input *by default*, except that `$` also matches before a trailing newline, if any.
  - To *always* match the very start and the very end - even with *multiline* input and the [multiline matching option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline) - use **`\A` and `\z`** instead (`\Z` to also match before a trailing newline, if any) - see [the anchors quick-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors).
- **`-match` (and its rarely used alias, `-imatch`) is case-*insensitive***, as PowerShell is in general; **use the `-cmatch` variant for case-*sensitive* matching**.
- Unless you truly need *string interpolation*, i.e. you need to embed the value of a PowerShell variable or expression in a regex pattern string<sup>[2]</sup>, **it's best to use *single-quoted* strings (`'...'`) to define regex patterns**, so as to prevent confusion over what elements PowerShell's [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`) interpolate up front vs. what the .NET regex engine will end up seeing.

To put it all together:

```sh
# To match case-*sensitively*, use -cmatch
$str -match '^E\d{6}[\dX]$'
```

<sup>Note: I've avoided use of `$Input` as a variable name, because it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) that shouldn't be used as a user variable.</sup>

Note:

- Strictly speaking, [character class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes) `\d` matches *all* Unicode characters classified as *decimal digits*, not just the ASCII-range digits `0` through `9`.
- While you can limit matching to ASCII-range digits with `[0..9]`, `\d` is a convenient shorthand that *in practice* is likely to work just fine, given that the non-ASCII-range decimal digits are from scripts rarely used in English contexts - see [the full list here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

---

<sup>[1] The LHS of `-match` can be a *collection* (array), in which case matching is performed against *each element* in that collection, and the return value then isn't `$true` or `$false`, but the *sub-array of matching items*. Also note that the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) is then *not* populated.</sup>

<sup>[2] Even then you may choose not to use an expandable string (`"..."`) and to instead construct the pattern based on a single-quoted string combined with `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), combined with escaping the variable value / expression via [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) to ensure literal treatment inside the pattern; e.g. `'^{0}' -f [regex]::Escape($PSHOME)`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for excellent summary.  Noted re `$Input` - in mitigation I never used that in my code, just as a placeholder for the purposes of asking my question but still that's no excuse.

Comment: Glad to hear it's helpful, @blackworx. It's tempting to use `$input`, and, conversely, it is regrettable that PowerShell didn't either choose a separate namespace for its automatic (built-in) variables or at least prefixed _all_ their names with `PS` (e.g., `$PSCulture`).

Answer (score 2):

> The input string must be 8 characters long, it must begin with an 'E', followed by six digits then either another digit or 'X'.

The real answer is

```
$Input -cmatch '^E[0-9]{6}[0-9X]\z'
```

Powershell `-match` operator is case insensitive, you must use the case sensitive `-cmatch`, or the `e123456x` input will be matched, too.

More, [`\d` matches any Unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-less-efficient-than-0-9), `[0-9]` will only match ASCII digits.

[`^` matches start of string, `\z` matches end of string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123738/11329890)

Comment: For single-line input, `^` and `$` as anchors work just fine. If you always want to match the very start and the very end of the input - even with multiline input and/or a trailing newline and/or the multiline matching option (`(?m)`) - use `\A` and `\z` (`\Z` to also match before a trailing newline). Combining `^` and `\z` is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specifically stated the match is case-insensitive.  However from the context of the rest of question I hope it was pretty clear that case was not the issue.