# MySQL RegularExpression (Limiter not working)

Tags: mysql, regex

**NOTICE TO THE MODS: DON'T DELETE/ DON'T CLOSE**
I asked this question earlier and the mods closed it because they thought it was similar to a question by another user. I have looked at the thread that they referred me to and it doesn't contain the kind of numeric problems that I have. That thread is [How do I match an entire string with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123455/how-do-i-match-an-entire-string-with-a-regex)

---

**My Question/Issue**:
REGEXP is returning a false positive.

```
SELECT '123456' REGEXP '[0-9]{1,4}' AS Test;
```

Based on what I've read, the part with the curly brace {1,4} means minimum of 1 occurrence and no more than 4. But from the above , the occurrence of the range [0-9] is more than 4 and yet the query returns a 1 instead of a 0. I've attached a screenshot. What am I missing? Thanks.

[Screenshot of the example in Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Ape.jpg)

Comment: MySQL `REGEXP` returns true if the expression matches **part** of the text.

Comment: the linked question is exactly what you are missing.  your example is matching because '123456' does indeed *contain* a 1-4 digit sequence.  if you mean to check that the entire string *is* a 1-4 digit sequence, you need anchors, as shown in the answer to the other question.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dc59aa8271985ad17e5e1a1b8fea045

Comment: @ysth , I didn't know about anchors. Thanks for the dbfiddle link. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT '123456' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,4}$' AS Test;
```

By "anchoring" you are asking to match the entire string.  The above will fail because of the limit of 4.

```
SELECT '123456' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,}$' AS Test;
```

Passes because it allows at least number of digits.

```
SELECT 'zzz123456' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,}$' AS Test; -- Fail
SELECT '123456' REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' AS Test;  -- pass
SELECT '' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,}$' AS Test;  -- fail (too short)
SELECT '' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AS Test;  -- same as {1,}
SELECT 'abc123456def' REGEXP '[0-9]{1,4}' AS Test; -- pass (no anchor)
SELECT 'abc123456def' REGEXP '^[^0-9]+[0-9]{1,4}[^0-9]+$' AS Test;  -- fail
SELECT 'abc123456def' REGEXP '[^0-9]*[0-9]+[^0-9]*' AS Test;  -- pass
```

Those last two include `[^0-9]`, which means "anything except 0-9.

**Elaboration on ^**

- At the *beginning* of the regexp, `^` "anchors" the processing at the beginning:  `REGEXP "^x"` means "starts with x"; `REGEXP "x"` succeeds if "x" is anywhere in the string.
- At the beginning of a "character set", `^` means "not":  `REGEXP "x[0-9]"` looks for x followed immediately by a digit' `REGEXP "x[^0-9]"` looks for x *not* immediately followed by a digit.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. They are very helpful. However, I'm confused about the true function of the caret symbol: ^

A video on Youtube by Sadia of the Crack Concepts channel, stated that the ^ symbol is used for negation. You said the same thing. However, the MySQL official documentation states that the symbol is used to denote the beginning of a pattern. The anchors example has also used it this way.

So, it seems the ^ symbol has two functions or am I mistaken?

Comment: The 6th example: SELECT 'abc123456def' REGEXP '[^0-9]*[0-9]{1,4}[^0-9]*' AS Test;    will pass because the string expression fits the pattern specified. I have also tested it in dbfiddle and it returned a 1.

Comment: @TheoFitchner - I added a discussion of the _two_ uses for caret.  My bad in #6; I will fix it.