# Laravel string validation; all char except #

Tags: php, laravel, regex-negation

I have a Laravel 10 project and I'm trying to  validate a string that can include any character (max 11 chars), except the # char

In my controller I tried this code, using regex

```
$request->validate([
    'code' => 'required|max:11|regex:/[^#]*/',
]);
```

but it doesn't work; if I wrote for example "CG#777" it accept the string, but I want it to discard.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: u need to put the `{0,11}` too for max 11 chars

Comment: @francisco That's what the separate validation rule `max:11` does.

Comment: I think you want `+` not `*`.

Comment: `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed, `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.

Comment: I'm not a Regex-pert, but you could implement a [Custom Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) using the [`Str::contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/strings#method-str-contains) helper, or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I match an entire string with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123455/how-do-i-match-an-entire-string-with-a-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```php
$request->validate([
    'code' => 'required|string|max:11|regex:/^[^#]+$/'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the right solution with the following regex:

```
^[^#]+$
```

Comment: Those are anchors `^$` if you're not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

It can be somewhat "simplified" (depending on your definition) by only using a single validation rule like so:

```
^[^#]{1,11}$
```

The `^` negates the matching options (so `[^#]` matches everything but the `#`), while `{1,11}` requires 1 to 11 characters.

The `^` and `$` are delimiters for the start and end of a string (may i recommend https://regex101.com/ for testing out your regexes).

This means you can leave out the `required` and `max:11` rules, however it might still be nice to have them for validation messages.